# How to Inner Join Three Tables and Return Maximum of Value in Third

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, inner-join

I have three tables as follows:

First table:

ordenes

```
id_orden | date | total | id_usuario
1        |15-may|50     | 1
2        |20-may|60     | 2
```

Second table:

usuario

```
id_usuario | name | phone
1          | abc  | 999
2          | def  | 888
```

Third table:

estado

```
id_orden | edo
1        | c
1        | b
1        | a
2        | b
2        | a
```

And this is the desired result:

Results:

```
id_orden | date | total | id_usuario | name | phone | maxedo
1        |15-may|50     | 1          | abc  | 999   | c
2        |20-may|60     | 2          | def  | 888   | b
```

- maxedo needs to be the maximum record from the edo in the third table after aggregating based on order.

How do I do this?

Comment: What was it you wanted? The results table? And maxedo is the maximum edo of an aggregated list I assume.

Comment: yes i need sql statmente to obtain results table and yes maxedo is the maximum letter no maters upload order

Comment: Also please remember to accept one of the answers that works for you or the best of them if all three work. (and upvote those that are useful). It helps following users (and contributors like myself of course).

Answer (score 0):

The below code sample gives you the result.

```
CREATE TABLE #ordenes(id_orden int, datevalue date, total int, id_usuario int)
INSERT INTO #ordenes
VALUES
(1,'20160515',50,1),
(2,'20160520',60,2)

CREATE TABLE #usuario(id_usuario int, name varchar(10), phone int)
INSERT INTO #usuario
VALUES 
(1,'abc',999),
(2,'def',888)

CREATE TABLE #estado(id_orden int, edo char(1))
INSERT INTO #estado
VALUES
(1,'c'),
(1,'b'),
(1,'a'),
(2,'b'),
(2,'a')

SELECT id_orden,datevalue,total,id_usuario,name,phone,edo as maxedo
FROM 
(SELECT o.id_orden,o.datevalue,o.total,o.id_usuario,u.name,u.phone,e.edo,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY o.id_orden ORDER BY e.edo DESC) as rnk
FROM #ordenes o
JOIN #usuario u
on o.id_usuario = u.id_usuario
join #estado e
on o.id_orden = e.id_orden) as t
where rnk = 1
```

Comment: Not sure if he wants to create the tables, merely get the result. Everything from the first SELECT onwards is what you'll want.

Comment: Ideally,he should have given the code to mimic his scenario. I thought the code sample might help somebody to try out the scenario in future also.

Answer (score 0):

The following should do the job (assuming edo is actually a numeric amount). I've included aliases using the `AS` command so you even get the column titles you want.

```
SELECT
    oe.id_orden AS id_orden,
    oe.date AS date,
    oe.total AS total,
    u.id_usario AS id_usuario,
    u.name AS name,
    u.phone AS phone,
    oe.maxedo AS maxedo
FROM usuario u
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT 
    o.id_orden AS id_orden,
    o.date AS date,
    o.total AS total,
    o.id_usuario AS id_usuario,
    e.maxestedo AS maxestedo
FROM ordenes o
INNER JOIN
(SELECT 
    id_orden AS id_orden,
    MAX(edo) AS maxedo
FROM estado
GROUP BY id_orden) e
ON e.id_orden=o.id_orden) oe
ON u.id_usuario=oe.id_usuario
```

In order of processing (which is not how SQL works but is useful way of breaking it down into steps) it goes:

1. Create table of Maximum edos (NB: `MAX` also works on alphabetical order);
2. Links this to `ordenes` using the id_ordene;
3. Joins this to `usuario` data using the `id_usuario`; and
4. Publishes this as a table in the required format.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be split into the following three steps:

**Step 1**: Calculate maximum edo for each id_orden in the table estado:

```
Select id_orden, max(edo) maxedo
From estado
Group By id_orden;
```

Result:

```
| id_orden | edo |
|   1      |  c  |
|   2      |  b  |
```

**Step 2**: Join the two tables ordenes and usuario on the key "id_usuario":

```
Select o.id_orden, o.date, o.total, o.id_usuario, u.name, u.phone 
From ordenes o Join usuario u
On o.id_usuario = u.id_usuario;
```

Result:

```
id_orden | date | total | id_usuario | name | phone 
1        |15-may|50     | 1          | abc  | 999   
2        |20-may|60     | 2          | def  | 888
```

**Step 3**: Join the table form the step1 and step2 on the key id_orden:

```
Select a.id_orden, a.date, a.total, a.id_usuario, a.name, a.phone, b.maxestado
From (Select o.id_orden, o.date, o.total, o.id_usuario, u.name, u.phone 
From ordenes o Inner Join usuario u
On o.id_usuario = u.id_usuario ) a 
Join (Select id_orden, max(edo) maxestado
From estado
Group By id_orden) b
On a.id_orden = b.id_orden;
```

Result:

```
id_orden | date | total | id_usuario | name | phone | maxedo
1        |15-may|50     | 1          | abc  | 999   |    c
2        |20-may|60     | 2          | def  | 888   |    b
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/a79a1/2

:)

Comment: I don´t know what i´m doing wrong but i can´t make it to work:

Comment: What is the problem you encountered?

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Select lc_t_ordenes.id_orden, lc_t_ordenes.fecha_registro, lc_t_ordenes.total, l' at line 1

***Please see my last answer***

Comment: almost 2 days and nothing, i´m thinking to pay a freelancer to do it

Comment: Still doesn't work? what's the problem now? (I've revised my answer and it works on the SQLfiddle now.)

Comment: i don´t know, the tables and fields have another names in the real database, when i change the names the sql gives me a error, it´s not your code it´s my mistake

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to get the max(edo) from the third table and group by id_orden, yes? try this.

```
select temp.*, max(edo) as maxedo
from estado 
inner join(
    select ordenes.*,usuario.name,usuario.phone 
    from ordenes,usuario 
    where ordenes.id_usuario = usuario.id_usuario
) as temp
on temp.id_orden = estado.id_orden 
group by estado.id_orden
```

Comment: never use implicit joins and never ever mix them with explicit joins as you can get unintended results when you do that.

Comment: Thank you. I know that  and I know it is much better to tell the database which columns we want  to get exactly.  And I just want to solve the problem for him/her as soon as possiable. Basic skills is necessary.  I'll solve the problems with more patient  and more detail. Thanks again.  @HLGEM